# Manipulating a jquery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery collection created with:

```
var children = $('span[data-Parent="7"]');
```

Now I would like to manipulate the css class of the items in that collection. I've tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var $child = children[i];
    if ($child.hasClass("red")) {
        $child.addClass("green");           
    }
```

But get errors stating that the object doesn't have a method hasClass. What is the proper way to get the elements of the collection to be document elements so they can be manipulated?

Comment: Doesn't answer the specific question asked, but just so it's said:  `children.filter('.red').addClass('green');` is equivalent to your loop.  Things get easier when you switch your thought process from manipulating elements to manipulating *sets* of elements.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must wrap the DOM element as a jQuery object. And iterating over elements using jQuery is usually done with the provided [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function :

```
$('span[data-Parent="7"]').each(function(){
   if ($(this).hasClass('red')) {
      $(this).addClass('green');
   }
});
```

Note that the whole code can be reduced to

```
$('span[data-Parent="7"].red').addClass('green');
```

Comment: Is it possible to access other data attributes? i.e. $(this).data-Mydata;  ?

Comment: You can access `$(this).data('Mydata')`, yes.

Comment: If that data is in an html attribute such as data-MyData="testdata"?

Comment: Yes I gave it a try but it always returned an undefined value. I have tried with $(this).attr('data-MyData') and it works as expected. I wonder if data is jquery version dependent? I have to stay with 1.9xx. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use `$.each`:

```
$.each(children, function(i, child) {
    if ($(child).hasClass("red")) {
        $(child).addClass("green");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cycle through each of the children and run the check in the `.each` loop.

```
var children = $('span[data-Parent="7"]');

children.each(function(index)
{
    var self = $(this);

    if (self.hasClass("red"))
    {
        self.addClass("green");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
var $child = $(children[i]);
//the rest of the code
```